# Splitting associative array into two arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I have an array of clubs

```
var clubs =[{
    team: {name: "fcb barca", rank: 4},
    team: {name: "man utd", rank: 16},
    team: {name: "man city", rank: 36},
    team: {name: "fcb liverpool", rank: 57}
}];
```

which I need to split into two arrays, so the expected result would be

```
  teams["fcb barca", "man utd" , "man city", "fcb liverpool"];
  rank[4,16,36,57];
```

I've tried the following code but doesn't seem to work

```
var team = [];
 var rank = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < clubs.length; i++){
   var tempArray1 = teams{{name: clubs[i].name, grade: clubs[i].rank}};
   var tempArray2 = teams{name: clubs[i].name, grade: clubs[i].rank};
   team.push( tempArray1 );
   rank.push( tempArray2 );
 };

console.log(team);
console.log(rank);
```

Comment: It would help if the code was valid.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what expected results are. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: And if you tell us what you want to do with your code

Comment: So loop over the array and push it into the other arrays.

Comment: sorry folks, I've edited the question to make it more clear. hope it helped

Comment: @MelbDev You still don't really care about JavaScript formatting. Please check spelling of the name of your variables, and the grammar, **if you want to get helped**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going to hate myself for doing this in five minutes.
But first of all, you code isn't close to valid at all at this moment.

Lets assess what's wrong here:

```
clubs[{
    team{name: "fcb barca", rank: 4}
    team{name: "man utd", rank: 16}
    team{name: "man city", rank: 36}
    team{name: "fcb liverpool", rank: 57}
}];
```

First off, clubs is missing a variable declaration like:

```
var clubs = [
```

Secondly, you are declaring clubs as an array with `[` however, your array is only containing one object, since you are following it with `{`

After this point, there are multiple issues. First one:

```
team{
```

is not a valid javascript object. However `team : {` would be. 
Now to the next issue, you have several objects following each other without a comma separation:

```
team : {name: "fcb barca", rank: 4}
team : {name: "man utd", rank: 16}
```

Which should look like:

```
team : {name: "fcb barca", rank: 4},
team : {name: "man utd", rank: 16}
```

This again however, if put correct would look like:

```
var clubs = [{
    team : {name: "fcb barca", rank: 4},
    team : {name: "man utd", rank: 16}
}];
```

Now we have another issue. You have one array, `clubs` which contains one object, which has several keys with the same name `team`

Thats just not gonna work.

**Your code should look like this:**

```
let clubs = [
    {name: "fcb barca", rank: 4},
    {name: "man utd", rank: 16},
    {name: "man city", rank: 36},
    {name: "fcb liverpool", rank: 57}
];
```

**OR, if you want the to be objects of teams**

```
let clubs = [
    { team: {name: "fcb barca", rank: 4} },
    { team: {name: "man utd", rank: 16} },
    { team: {name: "man city", rank: 36} },
    { team: {name: "fcb liverpool", rank: 57} }
];
```

Then, when you're syntax is correct, you could loop it like this:

```
let teams = [];
let ranks = [];

clubs.forEach(function(club){
    teams.push(club.name);
    ranks.push(club.rank);
});
console.log(teams);
console.log(ranks);
```

Comment: should hate yourself for using `for in` on arrays also

Comment: You're allowed to get my 2 thumbs up, only because of the fact that you've solved that very confusing puzzle, OP's invalid code

Comment: well, happy pappy @charlietfl ?

Comment: just suggesting best practices is all

Comment: The fact that i bothered to answer at 02:15 to this question while drunk should be good tbh :P

Comment: @OleHaugset It didn't work. because in my case each array is sub array, so

instead of 

let clubs = [
    {name: "fcb barca", rank: 4},
    {name: "man utd", rank: 16},
    {name: "man city", rank: 36},
    {name: "fcb liverpool", rank: 57}
];

mine is 

let clubs = [
    team{name: "fcb barca", rank: 4},
    team{name: "man utd", rank: 16},
    team{name: "man city", rank: 36},
    team{name: "fcb liverpool", rank: 57}
];

Comment: There is no valid javascript code that looks like : let clubs = [ team{name:"fcb barca" rank:4} ]. The team{} <- is not valid JS.

Comment: If you try to run that code through a JS engine you'll get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: @MelbDev lets hope my updated answer gives you some insight to whats wrong with your code. and good luck

Comment: @OleHaugset I figured it out, much thanks to your help :)

Comment: Well no probs. now since my answer is correct regarding to your question, you should accept my answer.

Comment: you're a champ mate! @OleHaugset